# SQL (Creating table): to check on max capacity from another table

Tags: mysql

**Table 1 - Bus details:**

-There is a different bus capacity

Bus1 Cap 10
Bus2 Cap 20

**Table 2 - booking details:**
-Records of passenger

Insert passenger 1 into bus1 only if the number of passengers < Bus1 Cap 10

So when creating SQL table 2 I want to ensure that the data is only addable if the max capacity of the bus is not hit. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Often people asking questions such as yours include, as text, sample data for their tables and a sample of the desired result. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: bring more clarity to your question.

Comment: You can write a function or stored procedure to solve the problem by checking the value of bus1 space.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot reference other rows in constraints. We can use a trigger `on insert` to check that there is space in the bus requested on that day.

> ```
> create table buses(
> id int,
> capacity int);
>
> insert into buses values(1,52);
>
> create table bookings(
> bus int,
> customer varchar(20),
> bDate date,
> places int);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER bus_capacity
>     BEFORE INSERT
>     ON bookings FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     declare cap int;
>     declare book int;
>     declare errMsg varchar(200);
>     select capacity into cap 
>          from buses
>          where id = new.bus;
>     select sum(places) into book
>            from bookings 
>            where bus = new.bus
>            and new.Bdate = Bdate;
>     if cap - book <= 0 then
>         set errMsg = concat(' Bus aleady fully booked. ', cast(book as char));
>         signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = errMsg;
>     end if;
> END
> ```

> ```
> /* we take 2 bookings for the
>  12th which fill the bus 1 */
> insert into bookings values
> (1,1,'2022-03-12',50),
> (1,2,'2022-03-12',2);
> ```

> ```
> /* and there is no room
> for the next customer */
> insert into bookings values
> (1,3,'2022-03-12',10);
> ```
>
> ```
>  Bus aleady fully booked. 52
> ```

This error message can be modified as required.

> ```
> /* who will have to wait
> until tomorrow */
> insert into bookings values
> (1,3,'2022-03-13',10);
> ```

> ```
> select * from bookings
> order by bDate;
> ```
>
> ```
> bus | customer | bDate      | places
> --: | :------- | :--------- | -----:
>   1 | 1        | 2022-03-12 |     50
>   1 | 2        | 2022-03-12 |      2
>   1 | 3        | 2022-03-13 |     10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=406b323e551636c9a95b207da08e5676)*